# How to detect whether an AsyncContext has timed out?

Tags: servlet-3.0

Is it possible to tell from an `AsyncContext`, whether it has completed, timed out or still waiting to be completed?

I know it's possible to listen for `timeout` or `complete` events, but I'd prefer not to define 4 `AsyncListener` listener methods just to record this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken Tomcat returns `null` when [`AsyncContext.getRequest()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/AsyncContext.html#getRequest%28%29) is called on timeouted `AsyncContext`.

I can not confirm this behaviour now, moreover it is not documented, hence should be considered unsafe and not portable.

BTW Tomcat was doing that because it **reuses** `HttpServletRequest` and response objects once the request is handled, just like it reuses servlet instances or threads. Sounds like insane optimization for me, but the spec does not forbid that...